# Как получить список ключей из Map?

Tags: java, android

Есть

```
Map<String,Double> map = new HashMap();
map.put("123", 5.0);
map.put("456", 3.4);
map.put("789", 2.8);
```

Как получить список названий всех ключей карты ("123","456","789")?

Comment: Да, список выводит, а как взять отдельно название ключа карты?

Comment: В  ArrayList заворачивать накладно. А задача такая: посмотреть размер карты и если она определенного размера. обратится к каждому элементу и заменить содержимое. А обратиться можно зная ключ записи. Для этого я и хотел узнать названия ключей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   import java.util.*;

    class Spisok{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Map<String,Double> map = new HashMap();
            map.put("123", 5.0);
            map.put("456", 3.4);
            map.put("789", 2.8);
            Set<String> setKeys = map.keySet();
            for(String k: setKeys){
                System.out.print("Ключ: " + k + " Значение: " + map.get(k));
                System.out.println();
            }
        }   
}
```